# android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android, eclipse

I just ran into this error and I don't know what it could cause...

```
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RadioButton cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at com.brobox.zahlenraten.MainActivity$ZahlFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:107)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2438)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-04 14:03:13.170: E/AndroidRuntime(16246): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So the strange thing is it says it cannot cast from android.widget.RadioButton to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView but apparantly I don't do that.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Random randomZahl = new Random();
        randomNum = randomZahl.nextInt((max) + 1) + 0;

        AdView adView = (AdView) zahlView.findViewById(R.id.adView); //Error line

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("3C7C32E5DD6FF99E1EE5A49DC7E90203").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and later:

```
// Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
    // RadioButtonGroup1
    case R.id.radio_10:
        if (checked) {
            max = 10;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rate eine Zahl wischen 0 und 10",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: What about layout xml? Could your post it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that recieves various views did recieved the adView and you allways try to cast the view into a RadioButton to test for a checked state. You can just move the `checked =` assigment into a switch case for your radio button, where you know for sure that the view is of RadioButton type to prevent the exception:

```
// Check which radio button was clicked
switch (view.getId()) {
// RadioButtonGroup1
case R.id.radio_10:
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    if (checked) {
        max = 10;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Rate eine Zahl wischen 0 und 10",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```